# Length of a rationals period in base $b$

Tags: rational-numbers

Okay working in base $b$ we are given a fraction of form $\frac{p}{q}$ with $p$ and $q$ coprime. We also assume that $b$ and $q$ are coprime so $\frac{p}{q}$ is purely periodic in base $b$. The question I have is what can I  say about this period. How tight of bounds can I get on it in terms of $q$?

I know that for an upper bound I have $q-1$, or at least I think I do.

For the lower bound I know I have $\frac{\log(q)}{log(b)}$.

So the range I have for the length of the period is $q - \frac{\log(q)}{\log(b)} - 1$ which is $O(q)$ is there a better bound I can put on it? I'd like $O(\log(q))$

This is related to [Length of period of decimal expansion of a fraction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/377683/length-of-period) but a more general question I believe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any three integers $m,n,b$ such that

$$m \ge 1,\quad n, b > 1\quad\text{ and }\quad\gcd(m,n) = \gcd(m,b) = \gcd(n,b) = 1$$

Let $\displaystyle\;\tau\left(\frac{m}{n}, b\right)\;$ be the "period" of the expansion of $\displaystyle\;\frac{m}{n}\;$ in base $b$.

Let $\lambda = \lambda(n)$ be the value of [Carmichael function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function) for $n$, we have

$$\gcd(b,n) = 1 \quad\implies\quad b^\lambda \equiv 1 \pmod n \quad\iff\quad n\;|\;b^\lambda - 1$$
Let $\displaystyle\;k = \frac{b^\lambda - 1}{n} \in \mathbb{Z}_{+}\;$, we have

$$\frac{m}{n} = \frac{km}{b^\lambda - 1} = km\sum_{\ell=1}^\infty b^{-\ell\lambda}
\quad\implies\quad\left.\tau\left( \frac{m}{n}, b \right) \right| \lambda.$$

This means $\lambda(n)$ is an upper bound for 
$\displaystyle\;\tau\left(\frac{m}{n}, b\right)\;$ 
for any choice of $m$ and $b$.

**Update**

In general, let $\mathbb{Z}_n^\times$ be the multiplicative subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{nZ}$ consists of ( equivalent classes of ) integers relative prime to $n$. Let $\mu = \text{ord}_n(b)$ be the order of $b$ in $\mathbb{Z}_n^\times$
(also known as [multiplicative order](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MultiplicativeOrder.html) or haupt-exponent of $b \pmod n$).
Using same argument as above, we get

$$n | b^\mu - 1 \quad\implies\quad
\left.\tau\left( \frac{m}{n}, b \right) \right| \text{ord}_n(b)\tag{*1a}$$

On the other direction, let $\displaystyle\;\nu = \tau\left( \frac{1}{n}, b \right)\;$. Being a period for the expansion of $\displaystyle\;\frac{1}{n}\;$ in base $b$, we can
find integers $\alpha, A, B$ such that

$$\frac{1}{n} = \frac{1}{b^\alpha}\left[ A + \frac{B}{b^\nu - 1}\right], \quad
\alpha \ge 0, A \ge 0, b^\nu - 1 > B > 0$$

It is clear $\displaystyle\;A = \left\lfloor\frac{b^\alpha}{n}\right\rfloor$. Introduce $C$ such that $b^\alpha = A n + C$, we can rewrite above condition as

$$\frac{C}{n} = \frac{B}{b^\nu - 1}\quad\iff\quad Bn = C(b^\nu - 1)
\quad\implies\quad n | C(b^\nu - 1)
$$

Since $\gcd(C,n) = \gcd(b^\alpha - An, n) = \gcd(b^\alpha,n) = 1$, this leads to

$$n | b^\nu - 1
\quad\implies\quad
\left.\tau\left(\frac{1}{n},b\right)\right| \text{ord}_n(b)\tag{*1b}$$

Combine $(*1a)$ and $(*1b)$, we get

$$\tau\left(\frac{1}{n},b\right) = \text{ord}_n(b)
\quad\implies\quad
\max\left\{\; \tau\left( \frac{m}{n}, b \right) : m \ge 1 \;\right\} = \text{ord}_n(b)
$$
i.e. $\text{ord}_n(b)$ is the least upper bound of $\displaystyle\;\tau\left(\frac{m}{n},b\right)\;$ when we fix $b$ and allow $m$ to vary.

Let $n = p_1^{e_1} p_2^{e_2} \cdots p_r^{e_r}$ be the factorization of $n$ into its prime factors. We know as a group, $\mathbb{Z}_n^\times$ is isomorphic to the direct product of 
its prime components.

$$\mathbb{Z}_n^\times = 
\mathbb{Z}_{p_1^{e_1}}^\times \times
\mathbb{Z}_{p_2^{e_2}}^\times \times
\cdots
\mathbb{Z}_{p_r^{e_r}}^\times$$

The carmichael function of $n$ can be expressed in terms of its prime components

$$\lambda(n) = \text{lcm}( \lambda( p_1^{e_1} ), \lambda( p_2^{e_2} ), \cdots, \lambda( p_r^{e_r} ) )$$
We also know inside each $\mathbb{Z}_{p_i^{e_i}}^\times$, there is a element whose order equal to $\lambda( p_i^{e_i} )$. We can use
[Chinese remainder theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) to assemble these elements into an element $a \in \mathbb{Z}_{n}^\times$ such that
$$ \text{ord}_n(a) = \lambda(n)
\quad\implies\quad\tau\left(\frac{1}{n}, a \right) = \lambda(n)
$$

What this means is $\lambda(n)$ is not just a upper bound for $\displaystyle\;\tau\left(\frac{m}{n},b\right)\;$, it is the **least upper bound** when we allow both
$m$ and $b$ to vary.

> **Conclusion** -
>   If we don't impose more constraint on $b$, $\lambda(n)$ is the best bound we can have.

**Update 2**

About the question what sort of bound we will have when $b = 3$,
I have performed some numerical experiment. The result
indicate the period

$$\tau_n \stackrel{def}{=} \tau(\frac{1}{n},3) = \text{ord}_n(3)
=\text{lcm}\left(
\text{ord}_{p_1^{e_1}}(3), \text{ord}_{p_2^{e_2}}(3),\ldots,
\text{ord}_{p_r^{e_r}}(3)
\right)
$$ 
won't be anything simple that depends only on magnitude of $n$.
Instead, it depends strongly on how $n$ is factorized into its prime factors (as above formula suggests).

If we ignore the prime factorization of $n$, there aren't other pattern I can detect.
The only observation I have is:

> It seems more than half of the time, $\tau_n$ is actually equal to $\lambda(n)$.

For $2 \le n \le 10^4$, there are $6666$ numbers relative prime to $3$. 
Among these numbers, about $58.2\%$ of them have $\tau_n = \lambda(n)$ 
and close to $89.7\%$ of them $\tau_n \ge \frac{\lambda(n)}{5}$.

If we increase the range, say to $2 \le n \le 10^5$, the statistics is roughly
the same, $55.7\%$ for $\tau_n = \lambda(n)$ and $87.7\%$ for $\tau_n \ge \frac{\lambda(n)}{5}$.

Following is a table summarize this statistics for $n$ up to $10^4$.

$$\begin{array}{c:c:c}
\hline
s & \# \{ \lambda(n)/\tau_n = s\} & \# \{ n : \lambda/\tau_n \le s\}\\
\hline
1 & 3880 (58.21\%) & 3880 (58.21\%)\\
2 & 1285 (19.28\%) & 5165 (77.48\%)\\
3 & 369 ( 5.54\%) & 5534 (83.02\%)\\
4 & 256 ( 3.84\%) & 5790 (86.86\%)\\
5 & 190 ( 2.85\%) & 5980 (89.71\%)\\
6-10 & 353 ( 5.30\%) & 6333 (95.00\%)\\
11-15 & 165 ( 2.48\%) & 6498 (97.48\%)\\
16-20 & 37 ( 0.56\%) & 6535 (98.03\%)\\
21-25 & 27 ( 0.41\%) & 6562 (98.44\%)\\
26-50 & 57 ( 0.86\%) & 6619 (99.29\%)\\
51-75 & 19 ( 0.29\%) & 6638 (99.58\%)\\
76-100 & 10 ( 0.15\%) & 6648 (99.73\%)\\
\hline
\end{array}$$

**Update 3**

If you want to perform your own investigation, data of $\text{ord}_n(b)$ is available on OEIS:

- $b = 2$ - [OEIS A002326](http://oeis.org/A002326),
- $b = 3,4\ldots9$ - [OEIS A050975](http://oeis.org/A050975),
  [OEIS A050976](http://oeis.org/A050976), $\ldots$, [OEIS A050981](http://oeis.org/A050981)
- $b = 10$ - [OEIS A092329](http://oeis.org/A002329)

In Mathematica, you can also compute $\lambda(n)$ and $\text{ord}_n(b)$ yourself
using the commands `Carmichael[n]` and `MultiplicativeOrder[b,n]`.

Comment: What is the big O of the carmicheal function? Also does it have to be divisible by the actual length or is it just an upper bound?

Comment: @ruler501 look at the [average and typical value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function#Average_and_typical_value) part of the wiki page. It is basically $O(n)$.

Comment: So basically doesn't improve the bounds by more than a constant. Still interesting though.  I think the average should be around the minimum times a constant but I'm not sure how to prove that

Comment: @ruler501 in this state, it doesn't improve that much. However, I suspect $\lambda(q)$ is not only an upper bound but the least upper bound when we vary $p$. I'm trying to find a proof of that.

Comment: @rule501. Okay, $\lambda(n)$ is not the least upper bound if we fix $b$ and only allow to vary $p$. However, it is the least upper bound when we allow both $b$ and $q$ to vary. See update of answer (please note that I've switch to use $m/n$ instead of $p/q$ in the updated answer).

Comment: So if we restricted $b$ to be say $3$ what kind of bound would we get?

Comment: @ruler501. I have no idea. However, numerical experiment suggests more than half of the time, the period $\tau\left(\frac{1}{n},3\right)$ is actually equal to $\lambda(n)$. See update of answer.