# How are the Periods of the Decimal Expansions of $\frac{p}{q}$ and $\frac{q}{p}$ Related?

Tags: number-theory, fractions, rational-numbers, decimal-expansion

In an excellent post several years ago, we learn that the period of the decimal expansion of a rational number $\frac{p}{q}$ must divide the multiplicative order of $10\pmod q$ assuming that there are no factors of $2$ or $5$ in $q$.

[Length of period of decimal expansion of a fraction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/377683/length-of-period-of-decimal-expansion-of-a-fraction)

How does the period of the decimal expansion of $\frac{q}{p}$ relate to that of $\frac{p}{q}$? Let us assume that $p, q$ are coprime integers. (I have added this in response to an answer given.)

Comment: Why should they be related?

Comment: If they are not, can we prove that?

Comment: Pick $p,q$ unrelated, with 10 is a primitive root both mod p and mod q, for example.

Comment: I think you answered your own question in the post.  The period of $\frac pq$ must divide the multiplicative order of $10 \pmod q$ and the period of $\frac qp$ must divide the multiplicative order of $10\pmod q$.  As these multiplicative orders are completely unrelated the periods are unrelated.  Basically the numerator does very little to affect the period.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to prove this, but it seems like the periods of $\frac1q$ and $\frac pq$ are identical. So what you are asking is if for any primes $p$ $q$ how the periods of $\frac1p$ and $\frac1q$ are related. I would say they are not.

Comment: It's not necessary that $p, q$ be prime, but coprime. $p/q$ is presumed to be a fraction in lowest terms.