# How to check if the number after decimal point of the result of a division goes to infinity? Particularly, is this number any special?

Tags: infinity, decimal-expansion

I divide a number by a prime number and I observed the division in the below picture. I suspect that the result, quotient, goes to infinity. But how can I check if so? The big calculator showed the same repetitive pattern goes until 90000 digit only as it was apparently limited by the program.

How to check if the number after decimal point of the result of a division goes to infinity?

Also, as you see there is a repetitive pattern in the quotient, which is 473684210526315789. Is there anything mathematically special about this repetition?

Is there any other similar example division that gives a result going to infinity with a pattern like this?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: looks like $2118/19$

Comment: This has nothing to do with [tag:division-algebras]. Please read the tag descriptions before adding random ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the question is something like "how can I be sure that the pattern that seems to repeat will actually repeat forever?".

Every fraction of positive integers will have a decimal portion that repeats forever, and the length of the repeating portion will be less than the denominator (it will be exactly one less when the denominator is prime). For an in-depth explanation of that fact and more about the length of the repeating part, see answers on MSE like [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2611737/26369), which get into why [Euler's Totient Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem) is relevant.

The only remaining question is, what if we could be misled by a portion of decimals before the repeating portion? Well, the initial non-repeating part after the decimal point is caused by factors of 2 or 5 in the denominator, which don't affect the repeating business. For example, $\dfrac{1}{24}=0.0416666\ldots$, and we have three extra digits ($041$) before the repeating part, which has length 1 ($6$ repeats), which is certainly less than $24/2^3=3$.

So a general rule which will work okay for small denominators (but isn't best-possible), is this: throw away as many digits as there are factors of 2 and/or 5 in the denominator, and then the true repeating part will be less long than the denominator (even after you divide out by those 2s and 5s), so you can figure out the real answer.

For example, say you're calculating $\dfrac{4235}{38}$ and your calculator says $111.4473684210526315789473684210526315789473$ and you want to know if the $473684210526315789$s really repeat forever. Well, 38 is divisible by just one factor of 2 and no factors of 5, so we can throw away the first one digit after the decimal point (4) and worry just about the 473… 38/2=17, so the repeating part has length at most 16. $473684210526315789$ has length 16 and appears to repeat, so it does.

These methods are not efficient for certain larger fractions. For instance, $\dfrac{42815303527}{2499999750}$ has a repeating part of length only 7, but you'd need more clever techniques to be sure of it without calculating 10 million digits (or  ~6.6million if blindly using Euler totient function).

Answer (score 0):

It's not infinity, and it's not a question at all, it's just a rational number which is either integer or number with a repetitive decimal number.

like $\frac{1}{3}=0.33333333333\cdots$, do you think it's infinity??

But if you mean number of decimal points, it's obviously infinite.

Comment: Is this question clear now? How can you be sure the number after decimal point goes to infinity?

Answer (score 0):

The decimal expansion of a rational is always eventually periodic. Indeed, assume $r = \frac{a}{b}$ and without loss of generality $b > a$. Long division gives you the decimal expansion of $r$:
\begin{align*}
10a &= r_1 \cdot b + c_1\\
10c_1 &= r_2 \cdot b + c_2\\
10c_2 &= r_3 \cdot b + c_3\\
&\ \ \ \vdots
\end{align*}
where $0 \leq c_i \leq r-1$, i.e. $r = 0.r_1r_2r_3...$

By the pidgeonhole principle, we must have $c_i = c_j$ for some $j > i$. Therefore the expansion just repeats after the $j$-th decimal and the period is exactly the sequence of numbers between the $i$-th and the $j$-th digit. Note that the period can also be $0$, which means that the decimal expansion is finite.

Comment: Do you have an answer for the main question? How can I be sure if this number after decimal point goes to infinity?

Comment: I cannot answer this question because you did not say what (rational) number you have. But I told you how to find out: by long division.

Comment: is there not a method or web app to test  this in general?

Comment: Dude, I told you the method twice, it's called long division.

Comment: Also called division with remainder if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from your quirky terminology, what you've observed is a well-known fact about the decimal representation of real numbers. In particular, the decimal representation of any rational number (a quotient of two whole numbers whenever possible) either stops, or goes to infinity in a repetitive pattern, to follow your terminology. :)

Bow how do you know which rational numbers have a terminal decimal expansion and which extend to infinity repetitively? The key is in observing the denominator. If its prime factorisation contains factors other than $2$ or $5$ (can you see what this has to do with the *decimal* system), then it will not terminate. Otherwise it does terminate. Why? Because when the denominator is of the form $2^m5^n,$ you can always make this a power of ten by multiplying by $2^n5^m,$ for example, to get $10^{mn}.$ Thus, we can always convert a fraction which such a denominator into a decimal fraction (a decimal fraction is simply one whose denominator is a power of $10$). Otherwise, there's no way to convert the denominator to a power of $10$ since no multiple of such a number can be a power of $10.$ That is, if we have something involving $3^p7^q11^r\cdots,$ then no multiple of this can ever become of the form $10^N.$