# periodicity of primes inverses decimals in base b

Tags: arithmetic

I would like to prove the following:
Let b > 1 a natural.
Let p a prime number where p ^ b = 1.
The decimals of 1/p in base b are infinite and periodic from the first decimal (I've proven that already), let t be that period.

Prove that t | p-1

Comment: What do you mean by b ^ p = 1? The greatest common divisor?

Comment: I mean that b is prime with p, aka p doesn't divide b since p is prime

Comment: So it seems that your answer to 5xum is "yes". To clarify, you can edit your question to replace b ^ p = 1 by $b\land p=1$, or even better: "$p$ does not divide $b$".

Answer (score 0):

By the same proof as [when $b=10$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/377683), the period in base $b$ of $\frac1p$ is the [order of $b$ in the multiplicative group $(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)^*$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_order). By Lagrange's theorem, this order divides the order $p-1$ of that group.